# Why can't I request ASP.net pages in my website root?

Tags: asp.net, umbraco

I can request ASP.net pages which are in the '/umbraco' folder but not one's within the root of the site. Why is this?

Comment: Is your page is at root?

Comment: We need more details. How is your setup? Explain a little more, please.

Comment: Oh I thought it was standard Umbraco behavior!

Comment: The reason it loads is because /umbraco is a reserved url / path.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the url to the reserved url list (look at the web config). I recommend you put your asp.net web pages inside a custom folder such as /pages/ and then reserve the folder.

That way you can reserver the /pages/ and any pages inside there will load.  Just be sure to add your dlls to the bin etc etc.